# What is Adobe Bridge's keyboard shortcut for Go Back (OSX)?

Tags: adobe-bridge

It's neither Windows version's "delete" key or Finder's `command + [` so how do we go back?

It's obviously not `command + shift + \`, if you actually tried it on your keyboard. It will switch views.

And a "basic google search" mentioned by some [junior graphic designer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17070/what-s-the-difference-between-an-art-director-and-a-creative-director) who doesn't know the differences between an art director and a creative director through a basic Google search, certainly can't answer this question.

[image]

Comment: Questions about how to use the Adobe suite, particularly "Where is X command?" questions, are not on-topic for us. Please do a basic Google search or try SuperUser.

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum your comment is rather offensive. If a basic Google search can answer this question why would I ask?

Answer (score -2):

Probably you mean "Backspace" with "Delete"? Maybe it is: Command+Shift+\

Or you mean "go up" instead of "go back" then it is: Command+Up Arrow

Source: [Creative Suite / Adobe Bridge keyboard shortcuts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WS0DF94317-81FF-4202-8505-2E9E58036F5Ca.html)

Either way, I think this is not the place for this question.

Comment: Command+Shift+\ is go back in views, not go back in folder structure.